# Adobe AIR 18: namespace and sdk

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, namespaces, air, flash-builder

some years ago I developed an Adobe AIR application. Now I have to make some improvements and I have problems updating the SDKs.

I can't run my old projects without changing the SDK - if I try I get the error "Adobe AIR Debug Launcher has stopped working".

My old project used the Flex SDK 4.5.1 and the AIR SDK 3.0. Now I try to update to the current versions:

- Flex 4.6 (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html)
- AIR 18.0 (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html)

As I was used from my old projects, I downloaded and extracted the SDK files and then copied the AIR SDK into the Flex SDK. (as described [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/how-overlay-air-sdk-flex-sdk.html))

I saved the new SDK in programs/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder4/sdks and selected this SDK in the project settings in Flash Builder.

In the app.xml I set the application-Tag to:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/18.0">
```

and the namespaces are set to:

```
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
```

But when I save my project I get following error:

```
Could not resolve <mx:ViewStack> to a component implementation.
```

In the last 3 years I worked as a native iOS developer, so it's been a while since I worked with Adobe AIR for the last time. It's highly possible that I missed something but I can't find my mistake.

I appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ... I downloaded the wrong AIR SDK (with Flex Compiler).
With the correct SDK I could build and run without any problems.

Kind regards!